# Faster way of writing R data.frame into DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I'm struggling with performance of writing R data.frame into C# DataGridView. I've found the following solution ([original solution](http://www.r-bloggers.com/importing-and-displaying-a-data-frame-with-c-and-r-net/)), it's really great but if I have for instance data.frame 1000x1000 it's taking all my life.

```
DataFrame dataset = engine.Evaluate("string1").AsDataFrame(); // string1 is data.frame generated by R
engine.SetSymbol("dataset", dataset);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataset.ColumnCount; ++i)
                {
                    dgvDataFrame.ColumnCount++;
                    dgvDataFrame.Columns[i].Name = dataset.ColumnNames[i];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataset.RowCount; ++i)
                {
                    ++dgvDataFrame.RowCount;
                    dgvDataFrame.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = dataset.RowNames[i];

                    for (int k = 0; k < dataset.ColumnCount; ++k)
                    {
                        dgvDataFrame[k, i].Value = dataset[i, k];
                    }
                }
```

Do you happen to know if there is more efficient solution. Thank you very much for all of your hints or advises.